# Can't manage to run 2 while loops that create main links and sub drop down links in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

So I have one query which displays the main categories, and one query which displays the sub categories. I can't manage to display all the sub categories, in fact, it will only display the second database input for subcategories.

Here's the code

```
<?php

$mainlinks = mysql_query("select * from ns_categories");

while ($catlinks = mysql_fetch_array($mainlinks)) {
    $catlinkname = $catlinks['name'];
    $catlinkid = $catlinks['id'];

    $sublinks = mysql_query("select * from ns_subcategories where mainid='$catlinkid'");

    echo "<ul>";
    echo "<li><a href='products.php?mc=$catlinkid'>$catlinkname</a></li>";

    while ($catsublinks = mysql_fetch_array($sublinks)) {
        $sublinkname = $catsublinks['name'];
        $sublinkid = $catsublinks['id'];

        echo "<ul>";
        echo "<li><a href='products.php?sc=$sublinkid>$sublinkname</a></li>";
        echo "</ul>";
        echo "</ul>"
    }
}

?>
```

Also, when looking at the output from the subcategories get variables, the link leads me to

> `products.php?sc=3>Themes</a></li></ul></ul><ul><li><a href=`

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last `echo "</ul>"` should be outside the inner while loop.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a closing `'` on the line that generates your link.

Comment: Wow, fantastic! Thank you. Now my only problem is that the links all link to products.php?sc= instead of products.php?sc=(the id)

Comment: What is $sublinkname getting set to?